# Win7 desktop wallpaper, select all pictures in a folder via registry

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, desktop-customization

Is there a  location in the registry that allows me to select all pictures in a folder for the Win7 wallpaper rotation?

When my laptop goes off and on the docking station, that selection is somehow lost, and the wallpaper is fixed to one image. 
I want to be able to run a batch command that sets (in the registry) that selection to rotate all images again.

But I can't find the location of that checkbox in the registry anywhere so far.

Answer (score 0):

No need for registry

```
ATTRIB -H %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\slideshow.ini
ECHO.>%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\slideshow.ini
ATTRIB +H %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\slideshow.ini
```

Run that as a batch file, and restart.

Also just fyi the images that it would use are in the following location.

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles

Comment: Hi Ash, thanks for the help. I just tried to find the folders you point to. however i can only see that one picture is in there, named "TranscodedWallpaper.jpg". Once I activate the "Select All" from the normal wallapaper configurator screen, I see no other files in there, and no folder names "CashedFiles". Am I missing something there?

Comment: And you write that i would need to restart. My intention is to do this without a reboot, that's why i had aimed at a batch or similar.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an XY problem, and a batch file or registry edit shouldn't be required. What's happening is that by default your active power plan pauses the desktop wallpaper slide show when you switch to battery mode from being plugged in. You can change this easily if required:

1. Search for "power options" in the Start Menu search box
2. Next to the active power plan, click **Change plan settings**
3. Click **Change advanced power settings**
4. Expand **Desktop background settings** and then **Slide show**
5. Select **Available** instead of **Paused** for the **On battery** setting, then OK your way out

   [image: 1]

Comment: Hi Karan, thanks for looking at this from a whole different perspective. I checked the settings and found that they were alreade set to "Available". So that doesn't seem to be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Just to confirm, when it's on the docking station the slide show works, but when it's off it the wallpaper's static? Also, which laptop is this?